# Growing Cape Gooseberries in Brisbane, Australia

Tags: soft-fruit, gooseberries

For entirely irrational reasons (maybe because gooseberries hard to get here), I bought a Cape gooseberry seedling today.

Where I live in Brisbane, however, is not your typical cool climate for gooseberries!  Instead, it's a [humid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brisbane#Climate) [subtropical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humid_subtropical_climate) climate, with about 10-20°C in winter and 20-30°C in summer. No frost or snow in Winter and up to 40°C in Summer.

With this in mind, what sort of strategy should I employ to get the best out of this plant? Anyone grown one in a similar climate elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may depend on the type of gooseberry you have bought. Information I have says that only the Cape Gooseberry is suitable for Brisbane's climate (I'm in Brisbane too). Other types (American, Chinese, European) are a no-go, I'm afraid.

Ive never grown it myself, but the Cape Gooseberry is said to be reasonably hardy and can grow well in well drained soil with good amounts of sun and water.

Added 16/7/2013: Cape gooseberries are in the genus *Physalis* along with ground cherries, husk tomatoes and tomatillos. They are sub-tropical in origin and love the Brisbane climate. If you don't get frosts where you are it may grow for a number of years. They self-seed quite easily too.

Comment: They are indeed cape gooseberries.  Looks like good news :)